# I am trying to compare if a timestamp falls into 1 out of 3 bins. When I compare I get "Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and time"

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time

The objective of this code is to look at the 'time' column that had a dtype of datetime64 and determine if it is located within a certain time period bin. To create the bins and subsequence comparisons I use the following:

```
df_sum['start_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_sum['start_time'])
df_sum['time'] = df_sum['start_time'].dt.strftime('%H:%M')
df_sum['time']=pd.to_datetime(df_sum['time'])

am_peak_start = pd.Timestamp('2021-01-01 06:00:00').time()
am_peak_end = pd.Timestamp('2021-01-01 09:00:00').time()
md_peak_end = pd.Timestamp('2021-01-01 16:00:00').time()
pm_peak_end = pd.Timestamp('2021-01-01 19:00:00').time()

am_condition = ((df_sum['time'] >= am_peak_start) & (df_sum['time'] < am_peak_end))
md_condition = ((df_sum['time'] >= am_peak_end) & (df_sum['time'] < md_peak_end))
pm_condition = ((df_sum['time'] >=  md_peak_end) & (df_sum['time'] < pm_peak_end))

conditions = [am_condition, md_condition, pm_condition]
choices = ['am', 'md', 'pm']
df_sum['peak_period'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default = 'off-peak')
```

This however throws an error because datetime64 can't be compared to time. Not sure what I need to do for this one.

Comment: Can you change the `am_peak_start` etc. variables to be the same type as `df_sum['time']`?

Comment: Little bit more clarification. I don't care about the date. All I care about is the time. I modified my original post to show what I did for df_sum['time'].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this error will pop up every time you try to compare two different date/time related classes.

You could have a column hour in your df:

```
df_sum['hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df_sum['start_time']).dt.hour
```

And have your peaks in hours rather than hours:minutes, if you don't need them:

```
am_peak_start = pd.Timestamp('2021-01-01 06:00:00').time().hour
```

And then go on as intended

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Created a sample dataframe based on your example

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['time'] = np.array(['2021-01-01 06:00:00','2021-01-01 07:00:00','2021-01-01 08:00:00','2021-01-01 09:00:00','2021-01-01 09:55:00',
                 '2021-01-01 10:00:00','2021-01-01 17:00:00','2021-01-01 19:00:00','2021-01-01 20:00:00','2021-01-01 21:00:00'])
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
```

Here is the new column for conditions

```
df['new'] = np.where((df['time'].dt.hour >= 6) & (df['time'].dt.hour <= 9), 'am',
                     np.where((df['time'].dt.hour >= 9) & (df['time'].dt.hour <= 16), 'md',
                              np.where((df['time'].dt.hour >= 16) & (df['time'].dt.hour <= 19), 'pm','NA') ) )
```

Output:

```
    time    new
0   2021-01-01 06:00:00 am
1   2021-01-01 07:00:00 am
2   2021-01-01 08:00:00 am
3   2021-01-01 09:00:00 am
4   2021-01-01 09:55:00 am
5   2021-01-01 10:00:00 md
6   2021-01-01 17:00:00 pm
7   2021-01-01 19:00:00 pm
```

Feel free to modify the conditions in the code as per needs.